# Analyzing a discrete dynamical system for stable orbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have a discrete dynamical system $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ where $f(x,a) = \frac{2}{x} + \frac{x}{4} + a$ where $a = -1.5, -1.75, \cdots$ is a varying parameter. I wish to determine if a stable periodic orbit exists per each parameter $a$ and if so, find its period.

Let $a = -1.5$. So we have $f(x) = \frac{2}{x} + \frac{x}{4} -1.5$. This trajectory has equilibrium points at $x =-2.91485, \; 0.914854$ seen by this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih8vN.png).

From the following Mathematica code,

```
orb   = NestList[f, .714854, 30 ]
orb2  = NestList[f, -2.61485, 30]

{0.714854, 1.47649, 0.223688, 7.49695, 0.641012, 1.78032, 0.0684742, \
27.7252, 5.50343, 0.239268, 6.91864, 0.518734, 2.48522, -0.0739374, \
-28.5684, -8.7121, -3.90759, -2.98872, -2.91636, -2.91488, -2.91485, \
-2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, \
-2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485}

{-2.61485, -2.91857, -2.91491, -2.91486, -2.91485, -2.91485, \
-2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, \
-2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, \
-2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, \
-2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485, -2.91485}

ListPlot[orb, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True  ]
```

[image: trajectory plot of orb]

we can see that despite the starting point $x_0$, the trajectory always converges to $x =-2.91485$. Why? Should I have expected this? I initially thought that starting near 0.9... would cause the trajectory to converge to the $x = 0.914854$ equilibrium point. Is this wrong intuition? Can anyone please explain?

Comment: ?? The plot in the link does not show the graph of $f$, does it?

Comment: @Did It is the plot of $f(x) = \frac{2}{x} + \frac{x}{4} - 1.5 = x$ http://bit.ly/20KVJgl

Comment: A *local* version of the plot, rather, which quite mistakenly suggests that $f(x)\to0$ when $x\to+\infty$.

Comment: The phenomenon you are asking about is that the positive fixed point $x^*$ is unstable since $f'(x^*)<-1$, hence it repels every trajectory passing near, but not exactly at, it. And after some iterations, these trajectories pass to the negative part of the graph where a stable, attracting, fixed point $x^{**}$ awaits them.

Comment: I would like to first approach the problem numerically so I can better understand what is going on. Both derivatives at the equilibrium points (same thing as fixed points?) are positive. I thought that the equilibrium points would be stable because we can see in the plot that the trajectory converges to the equilibrium point.

Comment: Huh? The derivatives $f'(x^*)$ and $f'(x^{**})$ are both negative. And, as I said, $f'(x^*)<-1<f'(x^{**})<0$ hence $x^*$ is unstable while $x^{**}$ is stable.

Comment: Gah, I was editing my comment but accidentally refreshed the page. Anyway, I am not clear on the derivative rule you are referring to. Do you have a source that talks about this rule? Additionally, does the original (local) plot tell us anything about the trajectories? I feel my confusion stemmed from looking at that plot.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory#Stability_of_fixed_points

Comment: You have answered my question in full. Please feel free to add your comments as an Answer so I can accept it. If you can answer a related question. The period of the stable point we are discussing $x^{**}$ has period... $1$ correct? In the trajectory, if it was period $2$, I would have seen the points hopping back-and-fourth at the equilibrium point. Is there a way to find the period without looking at the plot?

Comment: The period of a fixed point is always 1, this is what being a fixed point means.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. What would "find its period" mean at the end of the exercise statement at the beginning of my post mean then? The period of the trajectory leading up to the fixed point?

Comment: It refers to the existence of periodic orbits. For periods at least 2, these do not pass by any fixed point.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for your time and all of the information! It's 4am where I live so I am going to sleep before I work on this exercise again.